# GCM Notification em forma de Dialog

Tags: android, google

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que recebe mensagens de alerta utilizando o Google Cloud Messaging, assim que recebe uma mensagem em segundo plano a App dispara uma notificação que fica na barra de notificações do Android com este código abaixo:

```
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Eu gostaria de exibir essa notificação como um `Dialog` na *home* do Android, algo semelhante como a App "Whoscall" faz ao receber uma ligação. Como é que isso poderia ser feito?

Comment: O WhatsApp também não faz o que você esta pedindo? O celular esta desligado, lançou uma GCM para o mesmo, e quando o usuário ligar o celular mesmo sem desbloquear o Dialog vai estar aparecendo.

Comment: isso, no caso em meu aparelho com Android 5.0 o WhatsApp realiza o mesmo processo que este código postado acima faz, exibe um icone na barra de notificação onde ao deslizar a barra para baixo é possível ver todas notificações do celular, e ao clicando sobre a notificação de minha aplicação ela abre a MainActivity, porém gostaria de enviar outra forma de notificação, exemplo se estiver mexendo a App do Facebook e receber uma notification, gostaria de exibir um pequeno Popup no centro da tela com 2 botões, porem vendo o Facebook atrás App para cancelar o Dialog desta notification.

Answer (score 1):

Erick, pelo que pesquisei isso parece ser uma má prática pois confunde o usuário e pode atrapalhar o usuário na tarefa que ele está fazendo. O correto nessa situação é utilizar as notifications mesmo.

Coloca uma notificação com as duas ações que tu pretende, é o melhor caminho.

Para mais informações: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html